# Как задать цикл скрипту на Python, чтобы он писал переменное допустим 5 раз?

Tags: python

Хочу написать скрипт так, чтобы он писал переменное message примерно сто раз, за весь день пробов, прошел через столько ошибок, но так и не нашел решение.
Вот в данный момент скрипт, при запуске пишет "Hello" с бесконечным циклом, пока я не закрою скрипт.

```
import time
import pyautogui

def SendScript():
    time.sleep(2)
    message = "Hello"

    while message != 0:
        print(message)
        pyautogui.typewrite(message.strip())
        pyautogui.press('enter')

SendScript()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
iterations = 100

for i in range(iterations):
    pass

while iterations > 0:
    iterations -= 1
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже второй день мучился над этим скриптом, теперь сработало :)